# Proper name for area defined by coordinate pair and radius

Tags: terminology

In defining geography objects within software, I have things such as a `City Area`, which is an area defined by the bounds of a city, or a `County Area`, defined by the county boundary.

**What is the proper term for an area defined by a center coordinate pair with a radius?**

I thought circle might be appropriate, but wasn't sure since that circle is bent along the earth's surface.  Is there a proper name for this?

Comment: Circle sounds fine to me. You could also call it a buffer, depending on your target audience.

Comment: @BradHards, Sounds good, thanks Brad!  I thought there was a chance I was over-complicating this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Circle" is overloaded and therefore ambiguous. Most often, this term refers to a circular *boundary*: a one-dimensional object. Mathematicians--who need to make careful distinctions like this--typically use ["disk"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_%28mathematics%29) (or its multidimensional generalization, ["ball"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_%28mathematics%29)) when denoting the circle with its interior. The concept is very general: it applies to any [metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space). This includes standard models of the earth's surface (including the sphere and ellipsoids).